# How do i find similarity between images that are this similar

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I need to find similarity between images that I have in a dataset that look like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiCS6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tFFv.jpg)

to a third image that also looks like previous images. a percentage of similarity is what i need. can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this problem? the dataset has 300 images and i need to compare one image to those 300 images.

Comment: Which features are you looking to compare for similarity exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of implementation to be used. Some of them use deep learning to find similar images. Good starting points:

- [How to Implement Image Similarity Using Deep Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-similarity-with-deep-learning-c17d83068f59): It is a simple and fast solution using **tensorflow** and **tensorflow_hub**. On the bottom of the blog it contains open-source frameworks and services for similarity search.
- [apple.github.io](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/image_similarity/): The **turicreate** package looks easy to use and there is hand-on example.
- [Image similarity with deep learning explained](https://peltarion.com/blog/data-science/image-similarity-explained): Read this if you want some explanation about how these system works.

Comment: Will it work for images that look this similar to each other?

Comment: It doesn't have to be as fancy as deep learning though. Given the simplicity of the images at hand one can just average the color across all pixels or break it down into equal number of segments and average the color within those then get the average of the respective differences or something like that. Really depends on what one is looking for.

Comment: I agree, it is not necessary to use complex deep learning models. Breaking down equal segment and averaging sounds like a convolution and average pooling operation in CNNs. However the advantage for using library is that It hides the implementation details.

Comment: i m getting values of 0 hue and 2 value in hsv for some images what's up with that?